# What's "an array of ol.style.Style" good for?

Tags: openlayers-3

A style of an [ol.layer.Vector](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.0.0/apidoc/ol.layer.Vector.html) can be set as `ol.style.Style`, a style function or an array of `ol.style.Style`. What's the array for and what does it do -- compared to just passing an `ol.style.Style` object?

I cannot find any information on this, neither in the official [API docs](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.0.0/apidoc/) nor in the [tutorials](http://openlayers.org/ol3-workshop/vector-style/style-intro.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Because I think this is still relevant and the edit queue is full for the approved answer, I'm posting this with the links updated and with code examples.**

**The most common way to see the array of styles in action is when drawing features** since this is default style in Openlayers. For the line to appear blue with a white border it has to have two styles since it can't be done with a single `Style`. Openlayers does this by default like this:

```js
styles['LineString'] = [
    new Style({
      stroke: new Stroke({
        color: white,
        width: width + 2,
      }),
    }),
    new Style({
      stroke: new Stroke({
        color: blue,
        width: width,
      }),
    }),
  ];
```

[source](https://github.com/openlayers/blob/main/src/ol/style/Style.js#L514-L527)

To expand on how usefull this feature could be you could check the [custom polygons example](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/polygon-styles.html). To have the vertices highlighted, they use two styles, one for the vertices and another for the polygon contour itself. Relevant piece of code:

```js
const styles = [
  new Style({
    stroke: new Stroke({
      color: 'blue',
      width: 3,
    }),
    fill: new Fill({
      color: 'rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.1)',
    }),
  }),
  new Style({
    image: new CircleStyle({
      radius: 5,
      fill: new Fill({
        color: 'orange',
      }),
    }),
    geometry: function (feature) {
      // return the coordinates of the first ring of the polygon
      const coordinates = feature.getGeometry().getCoordinates()[0];
      return new MultiPoint(coordinates);
    },
  }),
];
```

Answer (score 6):

If you look at the [draw features example](http://openlayers.org/en/master/examples/draw-features.html), when drawing lines, they are displayed in blue with a white border/outline.

These is achieved by styling the line twice, first with a large white line, then a thin blue line above.

There are 2 styles for the same geometry. It can’t be done with a single `ol.style.Style`, so to achieve this you need to pass an array of 2 styles: see [the source for this](https://github.com/openlayers/ol3/blob/master/src/ol/style/style.js#L307-L320).

Comment: Nice link the 2nd one.  Styling was a nightmare in OL2, and this looks like a useful improvement in OL3.